# Is it possible to display more than one month in menu view for JTCalendar ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jtcalendar

My current view after setting `calendarMenuView.contentRatio` to 0.3

[image]

How can I make it like May June July and so on as the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this channel: https://gitter.im/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar
Didn't exactly got what you want to do, but author will help you there for sure.

Comment: Actually, this link is for the `JTAppleCalendar` library. Which is different from the `JTCalendar` library. But yes, if he uses the JTAppleCalendar library, then he will be able to display 2 months at a time.